# Constructor props equivalent in React Hooks for history push

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to migrate one class component to function with hooks but i have a problem when try to change the url with my history.push.

With my class component this is the way to change the url:

```
  constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {
     // GeneralValidate: false,
      paisValue: '',
      paisError: true,
      loading: false,
      tipo: '',
  };

  }


.//more code here


 this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/Pais',
  state: { detail: 'hola' }
})
```

And works fine but in my function component the props its empty and i dont know how i cant use the history.push.

```
 const PaisForm = (props) => { 
 props.history.push("/Pais")
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks and sorry for the issues!

Comment: Are you wrapping your functional component in a `withRouter` hoc?

Comment: Connect with withRouter or pass history object from parent

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`props.history` and `props.location` are special `props` injected by `withRouter`, it works for `class` and `functional components`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'    

export const Component = withRouter(({ history, location }) =>{

})

class Comp extends Component {
    render(){
        const { location, history } = this.props
    }
}
export default withRouter(Comp)
```

Answer (score 4):

1st:

```
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom"
```

and wrap your component

```
export default withRouter (PaisForm);
```

2nd:

or pass history object from parent if parent has access to history, like below :

```
<PaisForm history={this.props.history}/>
```

3rd:

Use `useHistory` hooks from router

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

function PaisForm (props){
  const history = useHistory();

  return <button onClick={()=> history.push('/path')}>click</button>
}
```

Fixed typo

Comment: How about react-router-dom v6? It does not support withRouter anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can either wrap your component with the `withRouter` Higher-Order-Component, which will provide `history` as a prop:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Component = ({ history, ...props }) => {

    /* ... */

    history.push('/');

}

withRouter(Component);
```

Or you can use the hooks that came with the [latest update (`v5.1.0`)](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0). With these you do not have to wrap your functional component inside a HOC.

Available hooks are `useHistory` (`history` prop), `useLocation` (`location` prop), `useParams` (`params` object of `match` prop) and `useRouteMatch` (`match` prop).

```
import { useHistory } from `react-router`;

const Component = (props) => {
    const history = useHistory();

    /* ... */

    history.push('/');
}
```