# What is the difference between useHistory() and props.history in React Route

Tags: reactjs, routes, history

In my react function, I could write:

`const history = props.history;`
or
`const history = useHistory();`

Then I can use `history.push()` or `history.goBack()` in the same way.

So I wonder if they are different or not?

Comment: You can use `useHistory()` in any component, but `props.history` only in components where the `history` is available in props.

Comment: When I use Router, it seems the history prop was available for each route component without adding any extra code.

Comment: But does it get passed to the nested/children components?

Comment: I see, thank you. So they are the same but for different scenario.

Comment: @JTang, im using connected-react-router, will i get props.history for all the components?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RouteComponentProps vs useHistory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62290127/routecomponentprops-vs-usehistory)

Answer (score 1):

**Few Differences in this two**

1. useHistory() is react hook and props.history is properties of props
2. we cannot use useHistory() in class component.
3. we cannot use props.history in functional component directly, for that we have to wrap the component with withRouter. please follow this link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122219/constructor-props-equivalent-in-react-hooks-for-history-push)

**conclusion** :
if you are using class component then use props.history and if you are using functional component then use useHistory() hook