# RouteComponentProps vs useHistory

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Using React functional components and Typescript, would there be any difference between using the useHistory hook vs RouteComponentProps (react router v5.1)?

Example using RouteComponentProps :

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface PropsType extends RouteComponentProps {
    text: string;
}

const MyFunctionalComponent = ({
    text,
    history
    }: PropsType) => {
  
};
```

Example using useHistory:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

interface PropsType {
    text: string;
}
const MyFunctionalComponent = ({
    text
  }: PropsType) => {
    const history = useHistory();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I am exactly in the same situation, and I want to share my conclusions with you.

First of all, **the behavior of the programatic navigation with both approaches is the same, as they both use the same [`history`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) instance**, but there are some differences in the way of using them:

- Using the member `history` of `RouteComponentProps` forces you to drill it all the way down your component tree using props. There is nothing wrong with this approach, but if your component tree grows you may find yourself drilling through many layers of components.
- Using `useHistory` hook you can avoid the previous prop drilling and just allow you to use the `history` instance in any functional component. Note that [this hook is a quick stopgap for a future hook](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#usehistory) and will be replaced eventually by a `useNavigate` hook.

Personally, I find the `useHistory` hook a cleaner and more readable solution for long component trees, but I keep using the `history` instance of `RouteComponentProps` if the component is close or a direct child of a `Route` component.

Answer (score 0):

Para those who are having issues with useHistory, it has been replaced in react-router-dom v6, and now you should use useNavigate().

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate('/404');
```

You no longer need the "push".

I hope this helps!