# What is the best way to change the URL onClick or onSubmit in a React Class Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, browser-history

I'm aware of the useHistory hook for functional components in React, but in my application I have a class component that I want to make able to change the URL.

Is there an equivalent of useHistory for class based components? If not, what is the accepted way to accomplish this?

Comment: The closest equivalent is [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need something like this:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'    

export const Component = withRouter(({ history, location }) =>{

})

class Comp extends Component {
    render(){
        const { location, history } = this.props
    }
}
export default withRouter(Comp)
```

A similar question answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58122270/7306148