# Am I able to have a button with an onClick function inside of a router

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to have the button activate the onClick function and go to the route, but when I include the onClick the route does not work. Any Ideas?

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <h1>   </h1>
    <Link to='/ResultsPage'>
       <button type="submit" onClick={this.onCalculateSubmit} 
        class="btn btn-outline-success submit-button btn-lg">CALCULATE</button></Link>         
  </div>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/ResultsPage" exact>
      <ResultsPage />  
    </Route>  
  </Switch>  
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly in this way

```
<Link to='/ResultsPage' onClick={this.onCalculateSubmit}>CALCULATE</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a Link and a button and expect both click functionalities to work. If you want to redirect after click and have the button you can do this :

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';


const history = useHistory();

onCalculateSubmit(){
  //your code
  history.push('/ResultsPage')
}

<Router>
  <div>
    <h1>   </h1>
 
       <button type="submit" onClick={this.onCalculateSubmit} 
        class="btn btn-outline-success submit-button btn-lg">CALCULATE</button>  
  </div>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/ResultsPage" exact>
      <ResultsPage />  
    </Route>  
  </Switch>  
</Router>
```

Comment: I am doing all of this in a class component and am not able to use const history = useHistory(); Is there another, version of this that works in a class component

Comment: @ZachK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122219/constructor-props-equivalent-in-react-hooks-for-history-push