# hook call error: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks, eslint

I'm new to react component, getting this error when using react-hooks, here is my code, can anyone help me with that? This is the detail of the error.

This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

```
const newParams = "params"

// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
const history = useHistory();
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
const location = useLocation();


export class FullscreenDialog extends React.Component{

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { dialogShow: false };

        this.onDismissFullscreen = this.onDismissFullscreen.bind(this);
        this.openDialogWithButton = this.openDialogWithButton.bind(this);
    }

    openDialogWithButton() {
        updateSearch({history, location, newParams})
    }

    onDismissFullscreen() {

        closeDialog({ history, location, key: 'key' })
    }

    render(){
        const uniqueDialogId3 = 'notes';

        return (
            <>
                <DialogRoute id={uniqueDialogId3}>
                    <Layer id="fullscreenDialog" >
                        <UitkFullscreenDialog ariaLabel="Demo" dialogShow={true} returnFocusOnClose={true}>
                            <UitkToolbar
                                header="Toolbar heading"
                                iconLabel="Close the dialog"
                                key="UitkToolbar"
                                type={ToolbarType.CLOSE}
                            />
                            <UitkDialogContent key="UitkDialogContent-1">
                                <UitkParagraph key="UitkDialogContentParagraph" size={2}>
                                    test
                                </UitkParagraph>
                            </UitkDialogContent>
                        </UitkFullscreenDialog>
                    </Layer>
                </DialogRoute>
                <UitkLink inline={true}>
                    <button onClick={this.openDialogWithButton}>Open Fullscreen Dialog</button>
                </UitkLink>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to [convert your class component into a functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), then move your lines that call `useHistory()` and `useLocation()` inside the main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general rule of thumb is anything starting with "use" is going to be a hook and will not work in a class based component. You can Wrap your component in withRouter from react router dom to access the history prop that way if you want to stick with a class based component, [check that out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122219/constructor-props-equivalent-in-react-hooks-for-history-push). Otherwise you can switch to a functional component which would look like this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
const newParams = "params"

// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
const history = useHistory();
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
const location = useLocation();


const FullscreenDialog = ({closeDialog, updateSearch}) => {
const [dialogShow, setDialogShow] = useState(false)

const openDialogWithButton = () => {
    updateSearch({history, location, newParams})
}

const onDismissFullscreen = () => {
    closeDialog({ history, location, key: 'key' })
}

const uniqueDialogId3 = 'notes';

return (
    <>
    <DialogRoute id={uniqueDialogId3}>
        <Layer id="fullscreenDialog" >
            <UitkFullscreenDialog ariaLabel="Demo" dialogShow={true} returnFocusOnClose={true}>
                <UitkToolbar
                    header="Toolbar heading"
                    iconLabel="Close the dialog"
                    key="UitkToolbar"
                    type={ToolbarType.CLOSE}
                />
                <UitkDialogContent key="UitkDialogContent-1">
                    <UitkParagraph key="UitkDialogContentParagraph" size={2}>
                        test
                    </UitkParagraph>
                </UitkDialogContent>
            </UitkFullscreenDialog>
        </Layer>
    </DialogRoute>
    <UitkLink inline={true}>
        <button onClick={openDialogWithButton}>Open Fullscreen Dialog</button>
    </UitkLink>
</>
)
}
```